# How to reload an iframe using anything but loading without blinking

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, iframe

I load iframe by using a JavaScript code but it blinks every time it loads. How can I avoid blinking on loading of an iframe?

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(function () {
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");

  iframe1.src = "frmChatRequest.aspx";     
  }, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: You're reloading it every 4 seconds... of course it's going to blink.

Comment: If you want to get the optics more "smooth", maybe load the old and new content on top of each other and fade it (making the top one transparent in an animation)?

Comment: But there are some ways of getting iframes loaded without flickering every second and if also I increase the time limit to 15 second, it will blink

Comment: @arkascha N hows dat possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");
    if(iframe1.src == "frmChatRequest.aspx"){
        clearInterval(myInterval)
    }else{ 
        iframe1.src = "frmChatRequest.aspx";
    }  
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Try to reduce the interval time to 100 not 1000 :)

Comment: Very clever friend, But it will damage the efficiency of my application, bcoz the trip to database would be immense, Any other way mate

Comment: Can you please be more specific what exacly are you trying to do.

Comment: it is simple, I am loading an aspx page in which data is filled in datatable from database and then  a gridview is binded with a datatable hence I don't want the timeinterval to be that short